# unable to retrieve object from json file using key as control id

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json file with control id as key and value under response body as mentioned:

```
"Header": {
      "Data": {
         "@idType": "lab",
         "@id": "271093",
         "@name": "Rahul",
         "@techspecs": ""
      },
      "Template": {
         "@variant": "NA"
      },
      "Document": {
         "@name": "NA",
         "@exported": "NA"
      }
   },
   "Response": [
      {
         "@ctrl": "95245E0B-6D52-4398-8749-0090C8FC5CB9",
         "ResponseString": "+919844300558"
      }


I have written a code to retrieve a single response as there are lot of response. 
 const val1 = Object.keys(95245E0B-6D52-4398-8749-0090C8FC5CB9).number
```

but its not working

Comment: Please look up the reference for Object.keys before asking why it doesn't work. That function does something completely different from what you seem to think it does. Also, where are you even referring to the JSON object? Please show your code.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are wanting to accomplish. That usage of [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) makes no sense. Broken code is not a good substitute for a properly detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get a response with a specific key:

```js
const data = {
  "Header": {
    "Data": {
      "@idType": "lab",
      "@id": "271093",
      "@name": "Rahul",
      "@techspecs": ""
    },
    "Template": {
      "@variant": "NA"
    },
    "Document": {
      "@name": "NA",
      "@exported": "NA"
    }
  },
  "Response": [{
    "@ctrl": "95245E0B-6D52-4398-8749-0090C8FC5CB9",
    "ResponseString": "+919844300558"
  }]
};

const response = data.Response
  .find(response => response['@ctrl'] === '95245E0B-6D52-4398-8749-0090C8FC5CB9')
  .ResponseString;

console.log(response);
```

Comment: `find()` would be a more appropriate method as it breaks at first match and doesn't require creating a whole new array

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! I didn't even know that existed.